# Which is better between OneM2M and OCEAN

Tags: eclipse-plugin, leshan, onem2m

Which one to select between eclipse onem2m and ocean?

Anyone has done any comparison study?

Comment: Do you mean the Korean OCEAN initiative? (Open Alliance for IoT Standards) http://www.iotocean.org

Answer (score 2):

**OneM2M** is global initiative for IoT/M2M standard supported by global SDOs. Currently OneM2M is on release 3, pretty mature for uses.
Ocean is limited implementation of OneM2M standard. Other relevant implementation of OneM2M are Eclipse OM2M,IoTDM etc.

Answer (score 0):

### [iotOcean](http://www.iotocean.org/about/)

OCEAN (Open alliance for iot standard) is a global partnership based on open source and IoT standards. OCEAN aims to promote the development and commercialization of IoT platforms, products, and services by widespread adoption of IoT standards-compliant open source.

### [oneM2M](http://www.onem2m.org/about-onem2m/why-onem2m)

The purpose and goal of oneM2M is to develop technical specifications which address the need for a common M2M Service Layer that can be readily embedded within various hardware and software, and relied upon to connect the myriad of devices in the field with M2M application servers worldwide.

So oneM2M is the standardized technical specification and IoTOcean developed IoT platform based on oneM2M specification. [Mobius Yellow Turtle](http://www.iotmobius.com/) is the platform developed by IoTOcean which is based on oneM2M standards.